# Permission denied on Git config file

Tags: windows, git, permissions, file-permissions

I'm using Git GUI, and I was trying to create a new git repository for a folder on a remote server, which has been mapped on my Windows machine as `X:/`. I got following error message:

```
Failed to create repository
X:/blah

error: could not write config file
X:/blah/.git/config:input/output error
fatal: could not set 'core.repositoryformatversion' to '0'
```

I changed the permission for that folder on the remote server, but nothing changed. Any clue what was happening?

Tao